# Как отправить сообщение в чужой телеграм бот через URL?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Есть ли способ отправить сообщение чужому боту с помощью URL?

Задача примерно такая - в CRM системе нажимаем кнопку и в бота (клиента) уходит сообщение с видео

Я уже понял, что свой бот с чужим не общается.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots

Есть ли какие-то обходные пути?

Comment: Ответ в качестве камента: есть вариант добавить бот клиента в группу которой рулите вы и туда же добавить свой бот админом. В чужом боте должна быть логика различения I'd чата и I'd группы, тогда он сможет увидеть ваше сообщ.

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно. Можете добавить ответ, помечу как решение.

Comment: отправлять от имени пользователя с помощью telethon или pyrogram, для этого потребуется получить "креды" на https://my.telegram.org/auth

Comment: Проверил вариант с групповым чатом. Странно, но это не сработало. Бот клиента не слышит моего бота.